# What is the Structure/Architecture for White Label Application

Tags: android, git

I am preparing a white label application (called product later in this post) and I want to set up a very good architecture. This will easily and quickly set up a new client by changing the design, activating features...

I have several servers (dev, pre-prod, prod) so the flavorDimensions `server` are present in the product and the flavorDimension `client` is on the client side.

**I thought of this solution:** 
Set up one git per customer and one git for the product.

Clients will have access to the product code by git submodule. This allows me to separate the specific code from my client and the source code of the product.

```
Git -> Client 1
    Submodule -> Product v1
Git -> Client 2
    Submodule -> Product v1.2

...

Git -> Product v1.4
```

But I have a problem how to run it all correctly. The use of flavorDimensions `client` is hard because I need to make a copy-paste (with gradle) from my submodule to the app module before the build. 
The generation of this structure breaks Gradle because its need to be synced every time. *(Always Sync Now flag on Android Studio)*

So I ask myself, is a good architecture or not ? What do you think ?

Or do you have other ideas and how to implement them?

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm interesting take on it.
I have done similar things, but not quite like that. I use flavors for the deltas only. For example, themes, skins, app_icons, and Strings.xml. Maybe a few variations in layout or activities, but do my best to keep it generically served to minimize the maintenance of the code for various customer deployments as each additional flavor slows down the CI process significantly.

However, one key difference in what you are doing is you are not building a platform (aka everyone uses the same code GIT repo and API Server per se, you are building stand alone applications to supply full code and everything else to individual customers.

This sounds like it could be a maintenance nightmare, but if your situation requires that customer's get access to the code base for their product flavor, then I guess it makes sense. Not sure why they would get access to the code though as it is your product you are reskinning for customers right?

At any rate, you aren't asking for me to ask your reasoning haha, you are asking about architectural solutions. So here is my thoughts.

Make a task that copies the respective folders into a new module structure exactly like the modules you have now, but with changes to the package name so that they all slightly differ, then run your GIT push. You can run bash files from Gradle, so you can either write scripts and execute them from relative paths or you can write it directly in your Gradle file itself.

So I would update my Gradle to have separate dependency file like libs.gradle

> ->Put dependencies in that file like ext.libs {gson:"com.whatever:version"}
>   ->apply from ../libs.gradle
>   ->dependencies { libs.gson, etc..}

So i would assume your build task would do

> ->Create a new Module from All Source by copying files properly with new names if necessary to rename
>   ->if using maven server, then deploy aar or jar for compiled new module
>   ->Create a new dynamic Gradle file libs.gradle to replace current libs.gradle file that is updated source pointer to deployed artifacts
>   or created module
>   ->run gradlesync, when complete run assembleRelease, then you can do your git push etc..

All of this can be synchronized and done from terminal and localized into commands. Flavors may not help a ton in this area as they are part of the build process so you kinda need pre build processes which you can create tasks to do pre-build, but the key is the packaging of dependencies and updating your libs.gradle file and making sure that you replace it per flavor. Or if you have fixed flavors you can just make a specific libs.gradle for each flavor and update it based on the compiled dependencies.

I don't know your overall picture, but it is all doable. Hope that helps. Goodluck.

Comment: Regarding access to the git to the client, it's simple if he asks us if he will no longer work with us. We owe him our source code but considering it's a product. It only has access to its specific part so different git between each client.

I don't think it's a calvary to maintain if we use tags on our product. Ex: Client1 with Product v1.2. This make it possible to have the exact version of the product during a deployment on the store and makes it possible to simplify the resolving of the bugs in case of problems because one knows their version of the product.

Comment: I fully agree with the task configuration. It remains for me to find what task is used in the `Gradle Sync now` and to do it once my copy (buildSrc (dependencies, versionning ...) and src (product))

I also thought of using libraries for using the product in the client. It would be simpler. I just have to change the resources. I would have to test if it is possible to use a library activity in the Manifest.

Comment: Sure you can try bash gradlew --recompile-scripts or even bash gradlew      
  --refresh-dependencies but that one forces a fresh pull of all dependencies and would be slow. But sounds like you have a plan for the GIT piece, so the rest is just extracting the dependencies to a separate file and managing the libs.gradle file through flavors. Goodluck.